# Json mapping in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Upon upgrading to version 6 of Hibernate, the following code stopped working. It implements a "single table" hierarchy, with EntityA and EntityB classes inheriting from CommonEntity. These classes have properties of different types - PropertyTypeA and PropertyTypeB - which are mapped to columns in the database with a jsonb type.

Hibernate version 6.1.5.Final

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "table_test")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class CommonEntity {
    @Id
    protected Long id;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class EntityA extends CommonEntity {
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "property", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private PropertyTypeA property;

    record PropertyTypeA(String propertyA){}
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class EntityB extends CommonEntity {
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "property", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private PropertyTypeB property;

    record PropertyTypeB(String propertyB){}
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface CommonEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CommonEntity, Long> {
}
```

```
    @Autowired
    CommonEntityRepository repository;

    @Test
    void findEntities() {
      repository.findById(1L).ifPresent(System.out::println);  <- it's working
      repository.findById(2L).ifPresent(System.out::println);  <- throw hier
    }
}
```

```
    INSERT INTO public.table_test
            (id, type, property)
    VALUES(
'1',
        'A',
        '{
        "propertyA": "valueA"
}'::jsonb);

        INSERT INTO public.table_test
        (id, type, property)
        VALUES(
        '2',
        'B',
        '{
        "propertyB": "valueB"
        }'::jsonb);
        ;
```

When selecting an EntityB object from the database, an exception is thrown:

```
Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not deserialize string to java type: BasicJavaType(com.example.jpa.model.EntityA$PropertyTypeA)
    at org.hibernate.type.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.fromString(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JsonJdbcType$2.getObject(JsonJdbcType.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JsonJdbcType$2.doExtract(JsonJdbcType.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.readCurrentRowValues(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:298)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "propertyB" (class com.example.jpa.model.EntityA$PropertyTypeA), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "propertyA"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"propertyB": "valueB"}"; line: 1, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.example.jpa.model.EntityA$PropertyTypeA["propertyB"])
```

Comment: And this worked with the older Hibernate version? I'm very surprised that records should work

Comment: This worked with hibernate 5.x, "com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types" library and
annotations:
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Type(type = "jsonb")

Comment: The first insert seems to be wrong "propertyB": "valueA"

Comment: "Correct data is used in the test."

Comment: I would try this again in Hibernate 6.2, which is the version in which we announced support for doing this stuff. https://twitter.com/1ovthafew/status/1606256487428263937

Comment: I added a [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15929) with tests included.

Comment: I got same problem, did you find a workaround ?

Comment: Hibernate 6.2.2 does not solve the problem @GavinKing

Comment: See my response on the issue report. I *just* tested this on 6.2.2 and could not reproduce.

Comment: We had to remove JSONB Object to string to serialize/deserialize on '@PostLoad / '@PreUpdate on Object as workaround :(

Comment: Fixed in [6.2.5](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/versions/32158/tab/release-report-all-issues)

Answer (score -2):

try removing 'columnDefinition = "jsonb"'